# How to create funtion without checking T element in class by kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit2, okhttp

I am using retrofit library in my android project.
I will get a object Response after I sent request.
And I found that the Response has empty string value in message(), but message actually exsit in errorBody().
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ar0vy.png)
Is there any confirmation I should do for it?

I want to write a fun to use the Response, but I don't want to give T as an exact type.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/thV30.png)
Is there any way to make it available?

I have checked a lot of coverter problem in retrofit, but nothing helpful.